# Firebase deep query

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm using Angular 6 anf AngularFire2.

[image]

So, the task is to get all Collections where `publish:true`.

and the path to that Collection in my case is `v4/users/<userKey>/collections/<collectionKey>/`

Now, my question is, is it possible to get all of `publish:true` collection with one query?

Or do I have to make multiple queries in this case? Like:

1. get all users
2. for every user get all collections where `publish:true`

Comment: Firebase Database can order/filter results based on a value that's at a known path under the children of the nodes that are queried. There is no way to query all users based on a property in one of their collections. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested. As usual the solution is to add a data structure that allows your query. The simplest would be to add a top-level list of published collection IDs.

Comment: The other way is make your data redundant, for example keep all data under `published` collection as well, so when you can query easily